# Proving this inequality for an algorithm

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, induction

I want to prove that for all $a \ge 2$,

$$ a \cdot {2a-1 \choose a} \le 2 \cdot \sum_{i=0}^{a-1} i \cdot {2a-1 \choose i} $$

I am thinking the best way might be induction, but I have had no luck going from k to (k+1). Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint

Compare the RHS scalar (including the factor of $2$) applied against the specific term that involves
$\displaystyle \binom{2a - 1}{a-1} = \binom{2a - 1}{a}.$

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean by RHS scalar.

Comment: @HammadAli Set $a = 4$, compute the LHS, and then compute the RHS.  Pay particular attention to each term on the RHS.  If you still have a question, after you do that, leave me another comment.

Comment: Also I do see that equality, but cannot see how it can help me establish the inequality. It seems that gives an upper bound on the RHS.

Comment: I did that. What I notice is that each term in the RHS increases by an odd multiple of 2a-1, but I am still missing how this helps me prove the result?

Comment: @HammadAli When $a = 4$, the LHS is $4\binom{7}{4}$ and the RHS is $$2 \times \left\{\left[0 \times \binom{7}{0}\right] + \left[1 \times \binom{7}{1}\right] + \left[2 \times \binom{7}{2}\right] + \left[3 \times \binom{7}{3}\right]\right\}.$$  Note that $\binom{7}{3} = \binom{7}{4}$, and so on the LHS, you have $4 \binom{7}{4}$ and on the RHS, **for the last term only**, you have $(2 \times 3) \binom{7}{3}.$

Comment: Got it! And since all the other terms are also positive, the RHS is even larger than that! Thanks!